# When compiling a SDL2 program using g++, I get "Undefined reference to SDL_Init"

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to compile a C++ program with SDL2 and continue to get "Undefined reference to SDL_Init". My current compilation command is :

```
all:
    g++ -I SDL2/include  -L SDL2/lib/x64  -o main main.cpp -lmingw32 -lSDL2 -lSDL2main
```

My folder structure is as follows:
[image]

Comment: Which build of SDL2 did you download and which architecture is the default for your g++ setup? Try forcing 64bit with `-m64`

Comment: I am using the VC++ version of SDL. I am now using the 64bit version of g++ and seeing a new error: " multiple definition of `main'; " My main function looks like this:
```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, you cannot mix libraries compiled by different compilers. Use the MinGW ones.

Comment: Removing my SDLmain lib include from the g++ command and adding #define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED to main.cpp handled all my issues. Thank you for your help.